# java- how to use tokenizer with multiple delimiters to remove brackets and commas

Tags: java

If i give an input `string- "insert into tab1 values("abc", "xyz");"` ,i want them to be tokenized as, `array[] ={insert,into,tab1,values,"abc","xyz"}`

please help.

Answer (score 0):

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str,"(,); ");

Each character in the constructors delimiter(2nd parameter) field acts as one delimiter.Keep all your delimiters there where you need to split the string.

Try this and see

```
String str= "insert into tab1 values(\"abc\", \"xyz\");";

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str,"(,); ");

while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
    System.out.println(st.nextToken());
}
```

Comment: i tried this,but this simply returns a[]={into,values,"xyz"}

Comment: thanks, this did help, but the same program when executed on netbeans as a java application that reads the string from a textbox gives an incorrect result.

Comment: What is the output you are getting?Are you getting any error?

Comment: not an error, just incorrect values were being printed(same as above). i guess it was printing alternate tokens because we were printing "st.nextToken"

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting it using,

```
String[] tokens = string.split("\\s*(,|\(|\)|\\s)\\s*");
```

Answer (score 0):

The correction was made-

```
 String s="insert into tab1 values(\"abc\",\"xyz\");";           
String str[]=new String[100];
StringTokenizer tokenizer= new StringTokenizer(s,"(,); ");
while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        str[count]=tokenizer.nextToken();
        System.out.println(str[count]);
        count++;
    }
```

Thanks for all the help though.